# How to create Docker multistage build with Linux dependencies and environment vars from parent image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I have an application packages as .bin and it runs on rhel7-init base image. The following is the Dockerfile with the parent image and child image.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7-init:7.3 as base
COPY yum.repos.d/ /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN yum -y install sudo systemd
RUN yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.4/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat93-9.4-3.noarch.rpm -y && \
 yum install -y postgresql94
RUN export key=value && \
    installer.bin &> /root/install.log

FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7-init:7.3
COPY --from=base /opt/app/ /opt/app
COPY start_app /root/
RUN chmod +x /root/start_app
ENTRYPOINT [ "/root/start_app" ]
```

It has a start script given as ENTRYPOINT which configures a few things at runtime as it brings up the container. I copied the installed directory location to the new image from the parent image.

Now when I start my container, it shows dependencies on which sudo packages which were installed in the parent image.

How do I carry forward the installed packages of my parent base image to my new base image without adding too much size?

Can I also carry forward any env variables present in the installer used in the parent base image?

Answer (score 1):

You could forward environment variables etc from the parent image by writing to a file and the copy it into the next image. Then in your entrypoint somehow read it and export variables etc. But i would say it's a bit exotic design.

But in your case there seems to be quite a bit of dependencies on variables and packages so maybe it just easier to not user multi-stage at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'll attempt to address both issues.

**Reusing Linux dependencies from parent stage**

This should be possible by defining a common base stage in which the dependencies are installed. Example:

```
FROM ubuntu as base

RUN apt-get update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq -y install postgresql

FROM base as stage0
RUN which psql
# psql still here, should print /usr/bin/psql

FROM base as stage1
RUN which psql 
# psql still here, should print /usr/bin/psql
```

**Reusing Environment variables from parent stage**

This is a bit more tricky, nevertheless possible. Some options include:

1. Create a file with environment variables and use `COPY --from` to copy the file from another stage
2. Create a file with environment variables in the base stage and reuse that file across all stages.
3. Use a *global* `ARG` as suggested [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37345)

1) should be the clearest as there's nothing much new comparing to the Dockerfile posted in the question. It's just an extra file created on-demand and copied to a later stage.

2) should also be straightforward considering it's very similar to the solution shown for Linux dependencies. A file created in the base stage should be available in all `FROM base` stages.

3) is well explained in the mentioned link, but for the sake of completeness, should be something like this (Please refer to the [link](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37345) for more details):

```
ARG my_key=my_value

FROM ubuntu as stage1
ARG my_key
RUN echo $my_key
# should print my_value

FROM ubuntu as stage2
ARG my_key
RUN echo $my_key
# should print my_value
```

If you need to expose your environment variable to a running container, you may use `ENV` and feed it with the `ARG` value.

```
ARG my_key
ENV key=$my_key
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo $key"]
# should print my_value
```